# SQL - Replace specific char in a text

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to replace any "Blabla Pro**fessional** Blabla" or "Blabla Pro**fessionnel** Blabla" string value on a SQL query to "Pro" while keeping the "Blabla" values.
I can't figure it out.
I tried SUBSTRING function already.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: ...or possibly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace` function

```
REPLACE('Blabla Professional Blabla','Professional','Pro')
```

Or

```
REPLACE('Blabla Professionnel Blabla','Professionnel','Pro')
```